# convert byte index to character index

Tags: functions, multibyte

Some function in vim return a byte index instead of a character index (e.g. [match()](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#match%28%29)).
If the matched string contains multibyte characters this byte index differs from the character index.

Does vim provide a way to calculate the character index from such a byte index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it: [charidx()](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#charidx%28%29) allows this.